# Read selected item from binded property

Tags: xamarin.forms

I got my grid binded to viewmodel's `SelectedOrder.OrderItems`. I know which `Order` is `selected` but how to know once user clicks on `grid's row` (so specific `Item`) which `Item` was `selected` in view model?

**Property:**

```
public Order SelectedOrder
{
      get => _selectedOrder;
      set => SetValue(ref _selectedOrder, value);

}
```

**Order contains list of OrderItems which are shown on grid:**

```
public class Order : BaseModel
{
      public ObservableCollection<Order.Item> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

**Grid:**

```
<dataGrid:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderItems}" SelectionEnabled="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderItems}">
    <dataGrid:DataGrid.Columns>
        <dataGrid:DataGridColumn Title="ItemId" PropertyName="ItemId" />
        <dataGrid:DataGridColumn Title="ItemName" PropertyName="ItemId" />
    </dataGrid:DataGrid.Columns>
</dataGrid:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to bind `SelectedItem` to a property on your view model not to the collection of possible items. If you look in the Output window you should hopefully see some form of Binding errors.

Basically change this:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderItems}"
```

to something like:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrderItem}"
```

You will then also need to add the property to your view model.

e.g.

```
private Order.Item _selectedOrderItem;

public Order.Item SelectedOrderItem
{
      get => _selectedOrderItem;
      set => SetValue(ref _selectedOrderItem, value);
}
```

Comment: i thought about this but isn;t possible to use the way i have to read selected item?

Comment: @Arie sorry I am not sure I understand your question. Do you want the `SelectedOrderItem` property to be on your `Order` class?

Comment: No if you look OrderItems (list of Item) belongs to Order. Grid is binded to SelectedOrder.OrderItems (selected order is selected somewhere else so grid can already use it) so now grid uses inner list of slected orders that's why i use: ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderItems}" to show items on grid. So you mean to leave ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderItems}" as it is but create another property as you proposed and change this line: SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderItems}" to eg: SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrderItem}" (the new property). That's what you mean?

Comment: @Arie, yes exactly. You have to treat those 2 properties separately.

Comment: so simply saying it's not possible to read what i want based only on SelectedOrder i do need the second on.

Comment: That is correct, if you want to bind the `SelectedItem` in your view model then you need to bind it to something that is not your `ItemsSource`. Basically `ItemsSource` should provide multiple values to the control and `SelectedItem` should be a single value.